# Regex Second Non-Capturing Group?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following example here:

https://regex101.com/r/cE1sB4/3

Basically, I have a non-capturing regex group. However, I want to extend this so it does NOT include anything after DC=.

I have DC= in my non capturing group but it still includes the text between DC= and ,

Here is my regex (I am new to this!)

```
(?:OU=|CN=|DC=)(\w+[^,;])(?:,|$)
```

Example String:

```
CN=me,OU=test,OU=test,DC=donot,DC=includeme
```

Any help would be great.

I just want to include: me test test

Thanks!

Comment: *"I have the following example here"* - You are supposed to include your code with your question.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm storing it in an Array i C# and then using Array.split which seems to also include anything that was not in a non-captuing group (So if I remove DC= then it still returns EVERYTHING that is not captured in a group as one item

Comment: You're going to have to include the C# code here. One of the answers resolves the issue with the regex, if there is something wrong with the code, how can we help if you don't post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `DC=` from the non-capturing group and then print the group index 1 inorder to get the desired output.

```
(?:OU=|CN=)(\w+[^,;])(?:,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cE1sB4/4)

```
String input = @"CN=me,OU=test,OU=test,DC=donot,DC=includeme";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:OU=|CN=)(\w+[^,;])(?:,|$)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rSTJiu)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Didn't mean to include that!

Comment: I did but when using Array.Split on this, it returns DC=donot,DC=includeme as one item in the array

Answer (score 0):

How about a non-regex solution:

```
var input = "CN=me,OU=test,OU=test,DC=donot,DC=includeme";

var commaSplit = input.Split(',');

var keyValues = commaSplit.Select(x =>
{
    var equalsSplit = x.Split('=');
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        equalsSplit[0],
        equalsSplit[1]);
});

var notDcs = from kvp in keyValues
             where kvp.Key != "DC"
             select kvp.Value;

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", notDcs)); // me, test, test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want return true if DC= exists but don't capture that value, you can use this code:

```
(?:(?:OU|CN)=(\w+[^,;])|(?:DC)=(?:\w+[^,;]))(?:,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cE1sB4/5)